# Deleting reason of a question/answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I recently discovered a [question being deleted](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/27729/how-to-apologize-for-only-a-part-of-the-conflict) some very short time after it was posted (and answered, as I took time to do it ^^).

What bothers me is the lack of information about it (no comment or deletion reason). So we (***I***) don't know if it could be improved, or needs clarification, or can be undeleted, or voted to re-open, or else.

There was no real off-topic part (or one that couldn't be improved), or question about editing. Why would this happen straight out if the box without OP asking? Or did s/he?

Comment: This was a reposted question, posted to bypass system restrictions (closure of the first post). I'll try to remember to drop a comment next time.

Comment: OK thanks tink :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate a bit on the hasty comment I wrote yesterday:

I saw the question oneboxed when peaking at the chat transcript, and quickly realized it had already been asked (and closed) before. As such, I deleted the re-post.

I didn't notice it had an answer, somehow. (I do have an appointment with an optometrist soon). If I had, I would've probably dropped a comment somewhere, now I just mod-messaged the OP and thought everyone that needed to be notified, was notified.

I'll try my best to drop comments next time!

Comment: No big deal, but as you say, a small comment about the reason will inform everybody of why and what happened before :)